# Change my writeJsonFile function from GSON to Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have some code that takes in a list of descriptors and writes them to different JSON files using the GSON library. I am now trying to change that library to Jackson. I am not a Jackson expert so I'm looking for some help. Here is my code when I am using GSON:

Descriptor Class:

```
public class Descriptor {
    @SerializedName("BatchName")
    private String batchName;

    @SerializedName("Metadata")
    private Metadata metadata;

    @SerializedName("SampleInfo")
    private SampleInfoJsonModel sampleInfo;

    @SerializedName("Files")
    private List<String> files;

    @SerializedName("ClientData")
    private ClientData clientData;

    @SerializedName("CaseName")
    private String caseName;

    public Descriptor() {
        this.metadata = new Metadata();
        this.sampleInfo = new SampleInfoJsonModel();
        this.files = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.clientData = new ClientData();
    }

    public String getBatchName() {
        return batchName;
    }

    public void setBatchName(String batchName) {
        this.batchName = batchName;
    }

    public Metadata getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    public SampleInfoJsonModel getSampleInfo() {
        return sampleInfo;
    }

    public void setSampleInfo(SampleInfoJsonModel sampleInfo) {
        this.sampleInfo = sampleInfo;
    }

    public List<String> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<String> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public ClientData getClientData() {
        return clientData;
    }

    public void setClientData(ClientData clientData) {
        this.clientData = clientData;
    }

    public String getCaseName() {
        return caseName;
    }

    public void setCaseName(String caseName) {
        this.caseName = caseName;
    }

    public ClientData getClientDataNoCountryCodes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null ;
    }

}
```

My write JSON File function:

```
public static void writeJsonFile(List<Descriptor> descriptors) {

        try {
            for(Descriptor descriptor : descriptors) {
                BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("descriptor_"+descriptor.getCaseName()+".json"));
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

                buffWrite.write(gson.toJson(descriptor));

                buffWrite.close();
            }
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Error while writing to json file in writeJsonFile: ");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is what I have written in Jackson:

```
 BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("descriptor_"+descriptor.getCaseName()+".json"));
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
                buffWrite.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(descriptor));
```

Is this the equivalent of the code below in GSON?

```
BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("descriptor_"+descriptor.getCaseName()+".json"));
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                buffWrite.write(gson.toJson(descriptor));
                buffWrite.close();
```

Comment: I also think I am using the wrong annotations for the Descriptor class if I am using the Jackson library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for generating a pretty JSON output for your Object and trying to write it into a file.

You have to make sure that you are using `@SerializedName` equivalent annotation from jackson which is `@JsonProperty` on your object properties.

Also you can use following to prettify JSON using jackson ObjectMapper

`mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString( descriptorObj )`

NOTE that setting `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` will also help doing the same as you are already thinking.

Also [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) APIs are really useful for file related operations.

I hope this will help!

Comment: Once I marked it with the @JsonProperty Annotation things cleared up thanks